# ASP.net MVC removing repeated data calls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-authentication, data-caching

Ive got a asp.net mvc site that works with ASP.net Authentication. I have a UserInformation table which stores extra information on each user aswell. On pretty much every page i am calling to the database to pull the UserInformation record for the current user at least once.

Im thinking all these repeated data calls for the same information has to be overkill. Is there anyway i can cut these down? Caching? Storing the userinformation record for future use etc etc?

Im sure im not the first person to come across this issue, so i didnt want to reinvent the wheel.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could use a custom IIdentity and IPrincipal. Here's a nice [article](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2004/02/02/effectiveformsauth.html) describing how to achieve this (the interesting part is happening in the `btnAuthenticate_Click` method which in an ASP.NE MVC application would be the authenticate controller action, here is emitted the authentication ticket with custom data). In this example the idea is that the authentication ticket is manually created and the `userData` property is used to store additional information. This might not be appropriate for your case if you have lots of data because this is stored in a cookie. But instead of using the `userData` you could store it somewhere else like Session or Cache. You could also write a custom [`[Authorize]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) attribute to deal with the custom principal (the part that corresponds to the `Application_AuthenticateRequest` method in the article should go in this custom authorization filter in order to reconstruct the user back).